# Can't change input gain in Garageband for ipad

Tags: garage-band

I'm trying to record my trumpet with an external mic (SM57 Clone) and an iRig2 on iPad. This works perfectly fine on iPhone. But on iPad the sound comes out very warped. See this example. https://www.dropbox.com/s/47zzv7i7d3m4q6g/My%20Song%2011.m4a?dl=0

I can't seem to change the input gain. it just jumps up to max volume right away. Is there anything i can do?

Comment: The iRig 2 has an input gain control on it. One of these images has the controls labeled: https://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/irig2/index.php?p=images Are you saying this doesn’t work?

Comment: High input gain will not cause your recording to sound like.... that....  There is some other software issue here.

Comment: Is feedback causing the off sound and full gain jump?

Comment: as i said, this works perfectly fine with the same setup on Garageband for iPhone. The input gain control on the iRig doesn't do anything either, just makes the warped sound quieter.